# Update mongo collection with $set

Tags: python

Trying to update a collection and getting invalid syntax from '$'. This script works correctly inside robomongo GUI but not from the terminal..? Probably something simple but I can't seem to figure out why it's giving an error.

```
    collection.update({'title': "Super excited"},{ $set: {"fb_count": 300}}, {multi: true})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try following code, and I think you can specify `multi` as argument

```
collection.update({'title': "Super excited"}, {'$set': {"fb_count": 300}}, multi=True)
```

pleaser refer to [pymongo.collection.Collection.update](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes around `"$set"` (and `"multi"`).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with the same problem, putting the single quotes around $set alone did the trick, although I have not seen that as required in the documentation.